# How to regulate this weird installer?

Tags: windows, installer, minecraft

My sister plays Minecraft using her user account on the family Windows XP computer, and sometimes another computer (Win7). The client she uses is from [here](http://letoltes.mestermc.hu/mestermchutelepito.exe). The installer is very weird for several reasons:

- Does not register itself in the list of installed programs
- Places the program shortcut, without asking, on the Windows Desktop of all users. (Actually I haven't yet checked if it's in the All Users directory or in the separate directories.)

This second one is very annoying. In addition, *each time the game is run*, it re-inserts the shortcut icon, if it was deleted in the meantime, again on all users' desktops.

How can I stop that program from spamming my desktop?

Comment: Why is your sister using a non-official copy of Minecraft?  You can modify her User account so it doesn't have the ability to create shortcuts but really if the program is broken there isn't much you can do about it.

Comment: She probably uses that version because all of her friends play on the same server, and it's a Hungarian MC community. This is unrelated to the question. So how do I change her permissions so that she can place no shortcuts?

Comment: if it is a part of the `.exe` code, all you can do it is Hex-Edit it. unless there is a specific configuration in-game for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducing the rights of my sister's account to regular user made the installer unable to place its shortcut in the All Users/Desktop folder.

Additionally, I've found out that runs of the game did not create shortcuts; instead, because I deleted the shortcut, my sister couldn't find the game so she downloaded and ran the installer again :)